# Authorization has been denied for this request error when running webapi in MVC project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have created an ASP.Net MVC project with WebApi option. Then modified the values controller with the code below:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    static List<string> data = initList();

    private static List<string> initList()
    {
        var ret = new List<string>();
        ret.Add("value1");
        ret.Add( "value2" );

        return ret;
    }

    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return data ;
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return data[id];
    }

    // POST api/values
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
        data.Add(value);
    }

    // PUT api/values/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
        data[id] = value;
    }

    // DELETE api/values/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        data.RemoveAt(id);
    }
}
```

When I am running the project and navigating to API/values URL, the following image is showing error.

[image: error when running webapi MVC project].

The error description in text is:

> <Error>
>    Authorization has been denied for this request.  
>   </Error>

Comment: Add  [AllowAnonymous] to the controller

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. This resolved my error. But I need to know if [Authorize] is added to controller, do I need to configure something in order to run my controller?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following article about

[Authentication and Authorization in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api)

It will explain the different ways of how to use the `[Authorize]` and `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute on your controller/actions and any configurations you would need to do.

The following was taken from the linked article above:

> **Using the [Authorize] Attribute**
>
> Web API provides a built-in authorization filter,
>   `AuthorizeAttribute`. This filter checks whether the user is
>   authenticated. If not, it returns HTTP status code 401 (Unauthorized),
>   without invoking the action.
>
> You can apply the filter globally, at the controller level, or at the
>   level of inidivual actions.
>
> Globally: To restrict access for every Web API controller, add the
>   `AuthorizeAttribute` filter to the global filter list:
>
> ```
> public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config){
>     config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
> }
> ```
>
> Controller: To restrict access for a specific controller, add the
>   filter as an attribute to the controller:
>
> ```
> // Require authorization for all actions on the controller.
> [Authorize]
> public class ValuesController : ApiController
> {
>     public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id) { ... }
>     public HttpResponseMessage Post() { ... }
> }
> ```
>
> Action: To restrict access for specific actions, add the attribute to
>   the action method:
>
> ```
> public class ValuesController : ApiController
> {
>     public HttpResponseMessage Get() { ... }
>
>     // Require authorization for a specific action.
>     [Authorize]
>     public HttpResponseMessage Post() { ... }
> }
> ```
>
> Alternatively, you can restrict the controller and then allow
>   anonymous access to specific actions, by using the `[AllowAnonymous]`
>   attribute. In the following example, the Post method is restricted,
>   but the Get method allows anonymous access.
>
> ```
> [Authorize] 
> public class ValuesController : ApiController {
>     [AllowAnonymous]
>     public HttpResponseMessage Get() { ... }
>
>     public HttpResponseMessage Post() { ... } 
> }
> ```
>
> In the previous examples, the filter allows any authenticated user to
>   access the restricted methods; only anonymous users are kept out. You
>   can also limit access to specific users or to users in specific roles:
>
> ```
> // Restrict by user:
> [Authorize(Users="Alice,Bob")]
> public class ValuesController : ApiController
> {
> }
>
> // Restrict by role:
> [Authorize(Roles="Administrators")]
> public class ValuesController : ApiController
> {
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

So, I've been dealing with this error for awhile.

I didn't understand it at first, so I just removed  and lived with it.

I finally got sick of it, because it's rather stupid.  Microsoft wants a user to be authorized before they have signed in.

My error was looking for GET method which asks for HomeTown.  In my case, I had changed it to CityCode.

Since the user is not logged in, there is no CityCode to GET.  So, you get either a 402 or a 500 Resource Not Found.

I still don't understand it so, I gave CityCode some default data.  So, from MeController I put the following code:

```
Public Function [Get]() As GetViewModel
```

Dim userInfo As ApplicationUser = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId())

*Return New GetViewModel() With {.CityCode = "94110"}*

End Function

App loads completely error free now.

This is a quick fix, not a certified solution.